# Preprocessing Image dataset with numpy for CNN:Memory Error

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset (71094 train images and 17000 test) for which i need to train a CNN.During preprocessing , i tried creating a matrix using numpy that turns out to be ridiculously large(71094*100*100*3 for the train data) [all images are RGB 100 by 100].. Hence i get a memory error.How do i tackle the situation.??Pls help .
This is my code..

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


data_dir = './fashion-data/images/'
train_data = './fashion-data/train.txt'
test_data = './fashion-data/test.txt'


f = open(train_data, 'r').read()
ims = f.split('\n')
print len(ims)

train = np.zeros((71094, 100, 100, 3)) #this line causes the error..

for ix in range(train.shape[0]):
    i = cv2.imread(data_dir + ims[ix] + '.jpg')
    label = ims[ix].split('/')[0]

    train[ix, :, :, :] = cv2.resize(i, (100, 100))

print train[0]


train_labels = np.zeros((71094, 1))
for ix in range(train_labels.shape[0]):
    l = ims[ix].split('/')[0]
    train_labels[ix] = int(l)
print train_labels[0]

np.save('./data/train', train)
np.save('./data/train_labels', train_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem, and I believe its a common problem when working with image data.

There are a number of methods you can use to tackle this problem depending on what you would like to do.

1) It can make sense to sample the data from each image when training, so not to train on ALL 71094*100*100 pixels. This can be done simply, by creating a function which loads one image at a time, and samples your pixels. There is some argument that doing this randomly for each epoch can reduce overfitting, but again depends on the exact problem. Stratified sampling may also help to balance the classes should you be working with pixel classification.

2) mini-batch training - split your training data into small "mini-batches" and train on each of these individually. Your epoch will end after you have completed training on all of your mini-batches, with all of your data. Here you should, each epoch, randomise the order of the data in order to avoid overfitting.

3) Load and train one image at a time - similar to mini-batch training, but just use one image as a "mini-batch" for each iteration, and run a for-loop through all of the images in the folder. this way only 1x100x100x3 is stored in memory at a time. depending on the size of your memory, you could perhaps use more than one image per mini batch i.e. - Nx100x100x3, and run for 71094/N iterations to go over all training data

I hope this was clear.. and that it helps somewhat!